# Webforms - Getting Select Options From External Database - Not Working

Tags: webforms, database

I am trying to populate the webforms pre-built option list using a custom module. It works when manually including the values in the module, but when I try to query an external database to get the options it fails. Below is my code. I know that the database works, because views is currently able to get data using that connection and the query works when implemented directly in MySQL.

```
<?php

function mymodule_webform_select_options_info() {
    $items = array();
    $items['user_name'] = array(
        'title' => t('User Name'),
        'options callback' => '_webform_get_user_names'
    );
    return $items;
}

function _webform_get_user_names()
{
     $user_names = array();
     db_set_active('externaldatabase');
     $query = 'SELECT userID,userName FROM user_name';
     $select = db_query($query);
     while ($row = db_fetch_object($select)) {
         $id = $row->userID;
         $user_names[$id] = $row->userName;
     }
     db_set_active('default');
     return $user_names;
 }
```

Comment: Are you using drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: I am using Drupal 7

Comment: You're using DB API code from Drupal 6...

Comment: When I throw in WHERE restrictions to the queries it is saying that the column is not found. Is there anyway to confirm that it actually is connecting to the database and finding the table correctly?

Comment: I'm confused when I look at https://drupal.org/node/310072, it seems that the only real difference is that the table name is in curvy brackets. When I do that it still does not work. Note: I am assuming no where statements here. But now it provides the following error: Notice: Undefined index: aslist in webform_select_options_ajax()

Comment: If you're using Drupal 7 your code will throw a fatal exception, D7 doesn't have a db_fetch_object function